# Bindings from mapping have not been applied to the view

Tags: knockout.js

In me site, I would have expected my form inputs to have the default text values but no such luck..

```
   vm = { codeIncrementer: ko.mapping.fromJS({ fromNum: "1", toNum: "10", incrementerOutput: "", incrementerInput: "test code;<></" }) };
```

The vm var holds the correct values when I tryout putput them in the console..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For input tags, use the `value` binding rather than the `text` binding.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: fromNum" ... />
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" data-bind="text: fromNum" ... />
```